# namelookup with Unqualified name : C++0x draft n3290

Tags: c++, c++11, name-lookup

A point from the ISO C++ Draft n3290 : 3.4.0 2nd point

> A name “looked up in the context of an expression” is looked up as an unqualified name in the scope where the expression is found.

Would someone please explain this statement with an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says that the scope which contains the expression will be searched for the name. i.e.

```
namespace foo { 
  struct bar {
    void foobar() {
      do_something();
    }
  };
}
```

if you have this code the name `do_something` will be searched in the scope of `foobar`, `bar`, `foo` and in the global scope (and not in other namespaces, structs or function scopes)

Comment: Yep. It's core to the scoping/lookup rules.